# What's the difference between predict_proba and decision_function in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm studying a [scikit-learn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) (Classifier comparison) and got confused with `predict_proba` and `decision_function`.

They plot the classification results by drawing the contours using either  `Z = clf.decision_function()`, or `Z = clf.predict_proba()`.

What's the differences between these two? Is it so that each classification method has either of the two as score?

Which one is more proper to interpret the classification result and how should I choose from the two?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The latter, [`predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.libsvm.predict_proba.html) is a method of a (soft) classifier outputting the probability of the instance being in each of the classes.

The former, [`decision_function`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function), finds the distance to the separating hyperplane. For example, a(n) SVM classifier finds hyperplanes separating the space into areas associated with classification outcomes. This function, given a point, finds the distance to the separators.

I'd guess that `predict_prob` is more useful in your case, in general - the other method is more specific to the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Ami! I'm still wondering what do the classifiers use to compute the final predict, decision_fuction or the predict_prob? These two seems somehow connected, right?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed related; specifically they are inversely monotone.

Comment: @AmiTavory, may I ask you to have a look at a scikit-learn related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788611/python-find-document-similarity-to-show-related-ones ?

Answer (score 12):

Your example is

```
if hasattr(clf, "decision_function"):
    Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
else:
    Z = clf.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])[:, 1]
```

so the code uses `decision_function` if it exists. On the SVM case, `predict_proba` is computed (in the binary case)

> using Platt scaling

which [is both "expensive" and has "theoretical issues"](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities). That's why `decision_function` is used here. (as @Ami said, this is the *margin* -
 the  distance to the hyperplane, which is accessible without much further computation). In the SVM case, it is advised to

> use `decision_function` instead of `predict_proba`.

There are other `decision_function`s: [`SGDClassifier'`s](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.decision_function). Here, `predict_proba` depends on the loss function, and `decision_function` is universally available.