# AttributeError: 'MLPClassifier' object has no attribute 'decision_function'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I do not know why I'm getting that error while I'm trying to use `decision_function()`

```
model_1 = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=MLPClassifier())
model_1.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
model_1.decision_function(Xtrain)
```

I'm also getting that error using `DecisionTreeClassifier()`

Comment: What version of sci-kit learn you are using?

Comment: This method is not implemented for [MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), unlike some other methods such as [SVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function) and [logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.decision_function), which form hyperplanes.

Comment: @alift i'm using 0.22.1

Comment: @Reveille what is the difference between `decision_function` and `predict` in `BagginClassifier`? I mean, `decision_function` returns the average output. What does `predict` return?

Comment: @Omar predict tells what class a sample belongs to, whereas decision_function tells how confident the model is that the sample belongs to that class. The latter is more related to predict_prob in what info it conveys. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543137/whats-the-difference-between-predict-proba-and-decision-function-in-scikit-lear) for that relevance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although BaggingClassifier does have the `decision_function` method, it would only work if the base_estimator selected also supports that method; [`MLPClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.predict_proba) does not. Some models like SVM and logistic regression, which form hyperplanes, on the other hand, do. If you are interested in the confidence in predictions, you may consider the `predict_proba` method as a related measure; they are not at all the same though ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543137/whats-the-difference-between-predict-proba-and-decision-function-in-scikit-lear), [2](https://hunch.net/?p=317)).